# Multiple webpack alias configurations can't resolve modules

Tags: angularjs, typescript, webpack, ts-loader

I am working on an Angular 2 application written in Typescript, that is using webpack in conjunction with ts-loader to bundle everything together.

I am relying heavily on webpack's resolve.alias to cater for different build outputs and I have come across an issue.

When running a specific build, ts-loader is throwing an error saying it can not find a module that is used in the current build. This, I would assume, is due to the alias pointing to a different file.

eg: 
*file: myApp.ts*

```
import {Logger} from 'logger';

export class myApp {}
```

I have two alias JSON files, one is setup to point 'logger' at *remoteSystemLogger.ts*, and another which points at *consoleLogger.ts*

- Build A will use remoteSystemLogger,
- Build B will use consoleLogger

Now each logger class will import their relative dependencies. For instance:

*file: remoteSystemLogger.ts*

```
import {HTTP} from 'http';

export class Logger {}
```

The problem is, that when I run build B, I am getting an error saying:

> ERROR in remoteSystemLogger.ts
>
> error TS2307: Cannot find module 'http'.

http as well as remoteSystemLogger is currently not specified in the alias JSON file for Build B, as Build B should have no dependency on it.

The alias file that get's used for the webpack build is determined at build time via a param.

Here is an example of the resolve used in webpack config

```
let moduleAliasingConfig = `./alias/${buildType}.json`

 // ....

resolve: {
    root: [
      path.resolve('.'),
      path.resolve('node_modules')
    ],
    alias: moduleAliasingConfig,
    extensions: ['', '.ts', '.js']
  },
```

And here is the ts-loader config:

```
loaders: [
    {test: /\.ts$/, loaders: ['ts'], exclude: [/\.(spec|e2e)\.ts$/]}
]
```

I am not sure if maybe I have miss-configured something, or this is an issue with either the loader, webpack's resolver, or just my understanding of how the aliasing works.

As my understanding is, that webpack will traverse through my import/dependency tree, based on the alias file and my entry point.

Additional env info:

package.json setup:

- "ts-loader": "^1.2.1",
- "webpack": "^1.13.0"